# Find remote address of Netty HttpRequest

Tags: jax-rs, netty

I'm using netty and trying to define some mappings [using this library](https://github.com/caskdata/netty-http).
But I can't find out how to get user's remote address from HttpRequest.

Here's the example code :

```
public class TestHandler extends AbstractHttpHandler {
@Path("/ping")
@GET
public void testGet(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponder responder) {
    // remote address?
    responder.sendString(HttpResponseStatus.OK, "OK");
}
```

}

Comment: I resolved the problem by adding a ChannelHandler through the pipeline, got the remote address there and put it in request header.

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you about the library you are using but usually you would use `channel.remoteAddress()` to get the address of the remote peer.